# ObjectMapper customized with Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer not used by Jackson2RepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-test

I experience an issue with my test setup in Spring Boot:

- mongodb is used for this test
- data is bootstrapped from a `json/init-testdata.jsoninto` into mongodb using a `Jackson2RepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean`
- I used this setup before and I works smoothly; this time, however, I need to customize the Jackson `ObjectMapper` with a deserializer for `MyDomainObject`
- I added a `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer` to the class annotated with `@TestConfiguration`
- the `ObjectMapper` customized by `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer` isn't used when the data gets bootstrapped into mongodb; it only works if I instantiate and configure my own `ObjectMapper` in the method `getRepositoryPopulator` and then set it with `factory.setMapper(objectMapper)`
- I set breakpoints at the first line of the two methods `public Jackson2RepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean getRepositoryPopulator` and `public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jsonCustomizer` and it seems that `Jackson2RepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean` gets called before `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer`

Is there anything I can do to make my setup work with a `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer`? Or is the only way to go setting up my customized `ObjectMapper` in the `Jackson2RepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean`?

```
@TestConfiguration
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = TestDataPopulatorConfiguration.CONFIG_TEST_DATA_POPULATOR_JSON_RESOURCE)
public class TestDataPopulatorConfiguration {
    public static final String CONFIG_TEST_DATA_POPULATOR_JSON_RESOURCE = "test.data-populator.json-resource";

    @Bean
    public Jackson2RepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean getRepositoryPopulator(
            @Value("${" + CONFIG_TEST_DATA_POPULATOR_JSON_RESOURCE + "}") Resource jsonInputResource
    ) {
        Jackson2RepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean factory = new Jackson2RepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean();
        factory.setResources(new Resource[] {jsonInputResource});

//        setting up my own ObjectMapper here works fine
//        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
//        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
//        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
//        SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule();
//        simpleModule.addDeserializer(RetrosynthesisEngineInstance.class, new RetrosynthesisEngineInstanceDeserializer());
//        objectMapper.registerModule(simpleModule);
//        factory.setMapper(objectMapper);

        return factory;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jsonCustomizer()
    {
        return jacksonObjectMapperBuilder -> {
            jacksonObjectMapperBuilder.modulesToInstall(new JavaTimeModule());
            jacksonObjectMapperBuilder.deserializerByType(MyDomainObject.class, new MyDomainObjectDeserializer());
        };
    }
    
    public static class MyDomainObjectDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<MyDomainObject> {
        public MyDomainObjectDeserializer() {
            this(null);
        }

        public MyDomainObjectDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
            super(vc);
        }

        @Override
        public MyDomainObject deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
            JsonNode node = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);
            final String attributeOne = node.get("attributeOne").asText();
            return new MyDomainObject(attributeOne);
        }
    }
}
```

```
@DataMongoTest(properties = {
        TestDataPopulatorConfiguration.CONFIG_TEST_DATA_POPULATOR_JSON_RESOURCE + "=classpath:json/init-testdata.json"
})
@Testcontainers
@Import(TestDataPopulatorConfiguration.class)
public class MyTest {

  // test that relies on the data in init-testdata.json being present in mongodb

}
```